# Regular expression to validate US phone number with Custom validations

Tags: regex, validation

I want to create regular expression to validate US phone numbers, which will validate below need:

```
333 (till 1 to 3 digits)
333-3 (3 digits + 1 hyphen + 1 to 3 digit)
333-333-3333 (3 digits + 1 hyphen + 3 digit + 1 hyphen + 1 to 4 digits)
333-333-3333 3333 (3 digits + 1 hyphen + 3 digit + 1 hyphen + 4 digits + 1 space + 1 to 4 digits)
33333333333333 (any number of digit between 1 to 14)
```

I started regular expression from:

```
^\d{0-3}-\d{3}-\d{4}\s\d{4}$
```

Here I only want to validate above conditions, No special characters are allowed. I don't want to be generic. Only need to follow above conditions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the Help.

I have created below regex for above requirement, and it works for me.

```
^\d{0,3}$|^\d{3}-\d{1,3}$|^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{1,4}$|^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}\s{1}\d{1,4}$|^\d{1,14}$
```

Comment: with your regex, if you put nothing (a blank string) it will be accepted...
https://regex101.com/r/zF7zL5/1

Comment: Yes,  here I need value should be blank or valid value. So It is fulfilling my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You already described it, just translate that into a rexgex:

```
^\d{1,14}$       |         # (any number of digit between 1 to 14)
^\d{3}-\d{1,3}$  |         # (3 digits + 1 hyphen + 1 to 3 digit)
^\d{3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,4}$  | # (3 digits + 1 hyphen + 1 to 3 digit + 1 hyphen + 1 to 4 digits)
^\d{3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,4}\s\d{1,4}$ # (3 digits + 1 hyphen + 1 to 3 digit + 1 hyphen + 1 to 4 digits + 1 space + 1 to 4 digits)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zY8dQ5/2)